# Kendo-UI Context Menu

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-contextmenu

We are using kendo context menu in our code.After context menu initialization if we remove the target element and again we added the target to DOM context menu is not working .How to solve this issue.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li>delete</li>       
</ul>
<div class="parent" id="ParentDiv" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">            
</div>
```

**Script**

```
 $(".parent").append('<div><div> <div class="child">item 1</div><div class="child">item 2</div><div class="child">item 3</div></div></div>');
 $("#menu").kendoContextMenu({
     orientation: "vertical",
     target: ".child",
  });
 $(".parent").empty();
 $(".parent").append('<div><div> <div class="child">item 1</div><div class="child">item 2</div><div class="child">item 3</div></div></div>');
```

Comment: Pure guess, you need to initialize menu widget again?

Comment: no,we need context menu even after we remove and add the target element

Comment: we need to remove and add that div.because div was created and added dynamically in our code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you invoke `setOptions` and define again the `target`. Your code would be something like:

```
$(".parent").append('<div><div> <div class="child">item 1</div><div class="child">item 2</div><div class="child">item 3</div></div></div>');
$("#menu").kendoContextMenu({
    orientation: "vertical",
    target: ".child",
});
$(".parent").empty();
$(".parent").append('<div><div> <div class="child">item 1</div><div class="child">item 2</div><div class="child">item 3</div></div></div>');
// Redefine target
$("#menu").setOptions({target: ".child"});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".parent").append('<div><div> <div class="child">item 1</div><div class="child">item 2</div><div class="child">item 3</div></div></div>');
  $("#menu").kendoContextMenu({
    orientation: "vertical",
    target: ".child"
  });
  $("button").on("click", function() {
    $(".parent").empty();
    $(".parent").append('<div><div> <div class="child">item 4</div><div class="child">item 5</div><div class="child">item 6</div></div></div>');
    $("#menu").data("kendoContextMenu").setOptions({target: ".child"});
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.default.min.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

  <button id="button" class="k-button">Change</button>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li>delete</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="parent" id="ParentDiv" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create standalone context menu item and then open it on specified anchor. To do it you should use **alignToAnchor** option and method **open** with an anchor as first parameter

There is no need to recreate context menu each time you display it with different elements. Just open it with different anchors.

```
<div id="target">Target</div>
<ul id="context-menu">
    <li id="Item1">Item 1
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Item 1</li>
            <li>Sub Item 2</li>
            <li>Sub Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<li>Item 2
    <ul>
            <li>Sub Item 1</li>
            <li>Sub Item 2</li>
            <li>Sub Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<script>
// initialize the ContextMenu
$("#context-menu").kendoContextMenu({
    target: "#target",
    alignToAnchor: true
});
// get a reference to the ContextMenu widget
var contextMenu = $("#context-menu").data("kendoContextMenu");
// open the ContextMenu at 100px, 100px
contextMenu.open($('#target'));
```

Comment: Show your code. If you destroying widget as in a question, it can lead to memory leaks, and you need to re-initialize widget each time you add it. So i recommend use standalone widget as in my example.

Comment: we remove only the target element not a menu